# Numbering output lines in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I want to show the content of lists with arbitrary types, one element per line, numbered starting at 1 like this :

String Example:

```
> bs "Hallo"
1. 'H'
2. 'a'
3. 'l'
4. 'l'
5. 'o'
```

Integer Example

```
> bs [5,6,1,2]
1. 5
2. 6
3. 1
4. 2
```

Tuples Example

```
> bs [(4,"Test"),(3,"Aye"),(5,"Fives")]
1. (4,"Test")
2. (3,"Ayes")
3. (4,"Fives)
```

I found this to be one solution:

```
bs' :: Show a => [a] -> Integer -> IO ()
bs' [] _ = return ()
bs' (x:xs) y = do
  putStrLn  $ (show y) ++ ". " ++ (show x)
  bs' xs $ succ y

bs x = bs' x 1
```

1. As I am absolute beginner to Haskell I wonder what is the "best" way to solve this problem? Am I on the right trail or is that just plain "bad" Haskell.
2. How to output the Chars in the String example without the '' and still be able to output any type which has an instance of Show ?
3. I would like to know about other ways to solve this task, from different perspectives like: readability, efficiency, code reuse.

I also did it like this and found it even stranger (but somehow cool):

```
bs' :: Show a => [(Integer,a)] -> IO ()
bs' [] = return ()
bs' ((x1,x2):xs) = do
  putStrLn $ (show x1) ++ ". " ++ (show x2)
  bs' xs

bs x = bs' (zip [1..] x)
```

I have done about 25 years of imperative programming and being really interested in learning something new. At the same time if feels incredible "strange" to code in Haskell and I still can't imagine how a big project is done with this "crazy language from the moon" :)

EDIT: I wanna thank everybody. I choose one Answer because I have to but all are very helpful! I also want to say that the top solution I had was because "in the real problem" where that came from I had to skip some list elements and the numbering got wrong when using the zip approach. After reading all the answers I am pretty sure, that even then the solution is to first filter the list and then zip map the output function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is good to decompose your task into small parts.  In this case you want to 1) render each line by showing the element and prepending a number then 2. Print out each rendering on its own line in a terminal.

So the rendering is just some string munging:

```
renderLine :: Show a => Integer -> a -> String
renderLine i a = show i ++ ". " ++ show a
```

And the combination of many lines needs to pass in successive numbers into the render:

```
bs :: Show a => [a] -> String
bs = unlines . zipWith renderLine [1..]
```

This gives us results such as:

```
*Main> putStr $ bs "Hello"
1. 'H'
2. 'e'
3. 'l'
4. 'l'
5. 'o'
*Main> putStr $ bs [1,2,3,4]
1. 1
2. 2
3. 3
4. 4
*Main> putStr $ bs [(4,"Test"),(3,"Aye"),(5,"Fives")]
1. (4,"Test")
2. (3,"Aye")
3. (5,"Fives")
```

**Questions**

> As I am absolute beginner to Haskell I wonder what is the "best" way
>   to solve this problem? Am I on the right trail or is that just plain
>   "bad" Haskell.

I'd say the best way is the one that is cleanest to read for practiced Haskell programmers, which usually means using the common functions from Prelude, such as `zipWith`, and avoiding manual primitive recursion when possible.

> How to output the Chars in the String example without the '' and still
>   be able to output any type which has an instance of Show ?

To perform different operations on different types with the same function you'll need a type class.

**EDIT** I didn't read carefully enough. I now see you wanted to make this work for anything that is an instance of `Show`.

There are many long answers that can (and probably will) be given here about how making `Char` behave one way but then effectively lift all other `Show` instances leaves some ambiguity which the compiler must resolve.  I'll skip that and just tell you we need several extensions to the language via the `{-# LANGUAGE ... #-}` pragma you see below:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE IncoherentInstances #-}
renderLine :: BS a => Integer -> a -> String
renderLine i a = show i ++ ". " ++ r a

bs :: BS a => [a] -> String
bs = unlines . zipWith renderLine [1..]

class BS a where
    r :: a -> String

instance BS Char where
    r c = [c]

instance (Show a) => BS a where
    r = show
```

And in practice:

```
*Main> putStr $ bs [(4,"Test"),(3,"Aye"),(5,"Fives")]
1. (4,"Test")
2. (3,"Aye")
3. (5,"Fives")
*Main> putStr $ bs "Hello"
1. H
2. e
3. l
4. l
5. o
```

Comment: Thank you! Last part is really appreciated. Not because of the solution but because of showing how odd it gets and that it was a lost cause for me to figure that out myself.

Answer (score 5):

There is also `Text.Printf`, if you're nostalgic for `printf`:

```
import Text.Printf

bs :: Show a => [a] -> IO ()
bs = sequence_ . zipWith (\n x -> printf "%d. %s\n" n (show x)) [(1 :: Int)..]
```

Or if you don't want to use `printf`:

```
bs xs = sequence_ $ zipWith (\n x -> mapM_ putStr [show n, ". ", show x, "\n"]) [1..] xs
```

Neither of these is very idiomatic, I think most people would make a pure function that returns a string and then print that when necessary:

```
bs' xs = unlines $ zipWith (\n x -> show n ++ ". " ++ show x) [1..] xs

bs xs = putStr (bs' xs)
```

Comment: I did not use something like your last example because I was thinking this may not be efficient if the array is really large. Like `bs [1..1000000]`. 

That may be what makes me the "old imperative" guy as I just tried it and that solution even works for `bs [1..]`. What really baffles me!

Comment: I am confused about `printf`. At first I thought it does IO (print the stuff) but then I saw the answer below yours which is using `putStr` / `putStrLn` for output. I tested all and all of them seem to work as expected. `:t printf` does not helped me either. Your first example seems to only use `printf` ... why does it output something?

Comment: @OderWat: `[1..]` is not an array. It's a linked list, and where imperative languages use pointers, Haskell may have 'thunks' (unevaluated functions). `[1..]` is literally `fromEnum 1`. When evaluated, it becomes something like `1 : fromEnum 2`. After evaluating the tail, it's `1 : 2 : fromEnum 3`. As long as you don't eagerly evaluate this list (rather than using the data), infinite lists are fine.

Comment: @Rhymoid Sorry. I wrote Array but really did know about it being a List and also that it is not stored in memory but "generated" while being evaluated. I just (still) "feel like" that function needs to return a complete string so that putStr can do the output. It would then build a long string and use a lot of memory for that. So I thought: It may be able to output earlier and to prove this for mysqlf I used the endless list as parameter. I think that relates to "Lazy evaluation".

Comment: @OderWat `printf` is a function which uses Haskell's type class mechanism for overloading in an unusual way which even somewhat experienced Haskellers may find confusing. It manages to *both* take an arbitrary number of arguments *and* have its final result either be a `String` or a printing `IO` action according to how it's used.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen, I don't think the `printf` type class trickery is confusing to use, just confusing to implement.

Comment: Yeah.. I just found out about `printf "Test" :: String` results in a String "Test" and `printf "Test" :: IO ()` outputs Test ... not sure if thats cool but my question is answered! Thank you!

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena Fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

1 - You're using explicit recursion - nothing wrong with that but there are functions out there that already do this for you. Example using `forM_`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Text.Printf

bs l = forM_ (zip [1..] l) $ \(i, e) ->
  putStrLn $ printf "%d. %s" (i :: Int) $ show e
```

2 - It might be possible to do that using typeclass wizardry, but it's too much involved for a beginner.

3 - I like to split separate side-effects so that I can still use the function in a pure setting. In this example it could have been done like this:

```
bs :: Show a => [a] -> String
bs l = concatMap f (zip [1..] l)
  where f (i, e) = printf "%d. %s\n" (i :: Int) $ show e

putStr $ bs [1..10]
```

Comment: There is also `zipWithM`

Comment: To support (2) you might want an even more basic function with type `[String] -> String` which doesn't apply `show` to the list elements, allowing you to format each element however you want.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Sure, but the OP's requirement was that the function should work with any instance of Show.

Comment: Just being practical here :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer question 1: `zip [1..]` or variants is the way to do it. It exactly means what you want.

About question 2: the problem of `Show` is it's used for two purpose, printing things and serializing thing. In theory, `show` should be the opposite of `Read` and so should include all information needed to reconstruct the data from a string. So `show` adds quote and double quote to char and string and there is nothing you can do about it.

What you can do is,

- get on with it, and leave the quote or double quotes
- write your own `display` function which strips quote and double quotes (shouldn't be too hard 
  to do and it's a good exercise if you are learning haskell)
- another alternative is to use `printf` with `%v` which use

> The "%v" specifier is provided for all built-in types, and should be
>   provided for user-defined type formatters as well. It picks a "best"
>   representation for the given type. For the built-in types the "%v"
>   specifier is converted as follows:
>
> c      Char
>      u      other unsigned Integral
>      d      other signed Integral
>      g      RealFloat
>      s      String

Which will works for basic types, but I don't know how it behaves for `Showable` types.
It needs the last version of `base` and `GHC 7.8` so I can' try it.